# js tab to next input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 1-character input field which should autotab to next input when filled to maxlength (or "keyup") but what happens is the cursor just moves to the right (ouside of the input) and the function someFunc() shows the alert but the cursor doesn't tab to next input of ".input".

```js
function someFunc() {alert ("Hi!"); $(this).next('.inputs').focus();}
```

```html
<input type="text" tabindex = i id="R${i}" onkeyup="someFunc();" maxlength = "1" size = "1" class = "inputs" />
```

Comment: I've just tested and this works, you should add a running example to find the error.

Comment: You are right. It works perfectly on my webpage. But not in the main form. I've spent hours checking the css, the js and I find no clue as why this simple code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Heres another way you can do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length==$(this).attr("maxlength")){
            var i = $('input').index(this);
            $('input').eq(i+1).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength = "1" size = "1"  class = "inputs"  />
<input type="text" maxlength = "4" size = "4"  class = "inputs"  />
<input type="text" maxlength = "4" size = "4"  class = "inputs"  />
```

I'm not sure what's going on with your code. But here's a working sample for you that might help you.

```js
var elts = document.getElementsByClassName('inputs')
Array.from(elts).forEach(function(elt){
  elt.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || elt.value.length == 1) {

      elt.nextElementSibling.focus()
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputs" size ="1" id="0" maxlength="1"/>
<input type="text" class="inputs" size ="6" id="1" maxlength="5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. This old-school way was the only code that worked.

```
function someFunc(real_id) {
dog = real_id;
cat = dog.substring(1,5); cat++; cat++;
temp = "R" + cat; 
document.getElementById(temp).focus();
}

<input type="text" tabindex = i id="R${i}" onkeyup="someFunc(this.id);" maxlength = "1" size = "1" class = "inputs" />
```